How to refresh EC2 instance as part of an AutoScaling Group
As part of a CDK pipeline, an EC2 instance is started as part of an AutoScaling Group by the following code:
launch_template = ec2.LaunchTemplate(
            self,
            f"{self.resources_prefix}-launch-template",
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType(instance_type_identifier=self.ec2_type),
            machine_image=self.linux_ami,
            role=self.ec2_role,
            security_group=self.ec2_sg,
            user_data=ec2.UserData.custom(self.user_data),
        )

asg = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(
            self,
            f"{self.resources_prefix}-auto-scaling",
            vpc=self.ss_vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=[
                self.subnet_a,
                self.subnet_b,
            ]),
            launch_template=launch_template,
            desired_capacity=1,
            min_capacity=1,
            max_capacity=1,
        ) 

However, if I change the user_data and trigger again the pipeline, the EC2 instance is not refreshed reflecting the changed user_data.
I tried making the launching template id unique appending a UUID, but it doesn't make any difference.
How can I ensure that every time I run my pipeline this EC2 instance is always recreated?

Try adding update_policy=UpdatePolicy.rollingUpdate() in your AutoScaling construct. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling/AutoScalingGroup.html

You can try to use an AutoScaling Group lifecycle hook:
This will use a Lambda function to initiate an instance refresh. The Lambda function will be triggered after your stack is deployed to ensure the instance is recreated with the new user data.
